# How to get size of file uploaded to SQL-Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to tell how to get a file size that is uploaded to database?

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[File]
  FROM [dbo].[Reports]
```

I would like to be able to tell user the size of File which is `VarBinary(max)` field in MS SQL 2005/2008. How to do that?

Maybe the only way to do is to create another column and when inserting file i should also insert it's size in additional column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `datalength` function:

```
select ID, File, Length = datalength(File)
from dbo.Reports
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DATALENGTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function to retrieve the size of a VARBINARY